# Experience with IBPP interface for Firebird database

Tags: c++, database, firebird

I'd like to the ask guys with experience in Firebird and IBPP (especially the latter). I found a lot of positive posts about Firebird but I'm having a problem to decide about IBPP. The interface itself is clean and simple but it seems that the project does not have much of activity going on (maybe because it's very stable).

- Would you recommend IBPP for production environment?
- Is it thread-safe?
- Any known bugs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the points Milan mentioned:

- There is currently no way to use more than one client library when connecting to different databases, or even to specify which client library will be used. There is a certain hard-coded sequence of client library locations that are probed, and the first one that is found will be used for *all* connections. An IBPP version changing this has been hinted at for a very long time, but hasn't arrived yet. SVN `trunk` contains some code to deal with this, but I'd say that's alpha quality at most.
  And all of this holds true for Windows only, as on all other platforms the Firebird client library isn't loaded at runtime anyway.
- The library isn't thread-safe. That doesn't matter for the most part, as you should let each thread have its own connection, transaction and other assorted objects anyway. But IBPP uses its own smart pointer implementation, which is neither completely exception-safe nor thread-safe. Still, as long as you initialize the library from the main thread (before any other thread is created) and create and destroy IBPP objects in the same thread (so absolutely no sharing of objects with other threads!) using IBPP in multiple threads should work fine.
- If you can live with the points above (they may not matter to you, at all) it is certainly ready for production use. You can always change things you run into, as we did for FlameRobin too.

Comment: To mghie's first point: You're absolutely right, but going into the code and change the path of the client library is realy quite easy (file: "_ibpp.cpp" , section: GDS::Call()). Since the client library for the embedded database "fbembed.dll" also enables connections to a remote database (fbclient.dll seems to be a subset of fbembed.dll) you maybe never need to change the client library.

Comment: @Ergodicity: True, but then it's still a single client library for all connections. My answer was in regard to using multiple client libraries at the same time, which is a common feature of Firebird client tools like FlameRobin (which still doesn't have it). That wasn't possible then (more than 5 years ago), and AFAIK the situation isn't really different today. This in itself may be interesting in the context of the question, re "the project does not have much of activity going on"...

Comment: @mghie would you say, one should better use the [ibpp fork used in Flamerobin](https://github.com/mariuz/flamerobin/tree/master/src/ibpp) (in its current state)?

Comment: @Wolf: Sorry, I couldn't say. I've been away from FlameRobin for quite a few years now. You can have a look at the last few dozen messages on IBPP mailing list, where several issues with IBPP were discussed, and check whether the "FlameRobin fork" has fixed / improved upon those.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. Maybe meanwhile it's high time to start an own ibpp fork on GitHub ...

Answer (score 3):

IBPP is very stable and I would recommend it for production. That is, if you're going to use it for regular applications.

If you want to build an admin tool or something similar, then be prepared to go inside and get your hands dirty as some of the newer features (i.e. Firebird 2.5 stuff) that are not SQL but API improvements are not supported. For example, it is missing a layer that would expose the new trace API.

Anyway, go ahead and I use it. I have a bunch of IBPP applications in production for years, and, as Douglas wrote, FlameRobin is using IBPP and it works flawlessly (at least as far as DB layer is concerned).

The only thing to be careful about is NUMERIC fields, which are internally stored as integer+scale in Firebird. IBPP exposes those via C/C++ "double", but also via 16/32/64bit integer. So be very careful when retrieving such values, as you will get no warning. For example, if you have DECIMAL(18,2) field with value 254.00 in it, and you accidentaly read that into an integer, you will get 25400, not 254. Make sure you either read those in as double or scale yourself later. This is useful because you can safely convert 25400 to string and then add a decimal point, so you don't lose precision with double (it all depends on the kind of your application and which digits count, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell from experience because I've never used IBPP.
But apparently it's used by the flamerobin project so I'd trust it to be 'stable enough'.

Comment: but not the unchanged version from SourceForge https://sourceforge.net/projects/ibpp/files/ - FR also "moved" from SF to GitHub https://github.com/mariuz/flamerobin/tree/master/src/ibpp